# MS-SQL merge does not insert new rows

Tags: sql, merge

Run out of ideas why this is not working.
Despite there is no records on destination table it does not insert a single row.
Staging table got 473 rows.Any help would be appreciated.

```
    MERGE INTO [Shopify].[dbo].[metafields] AS destination
USING ( 
        SELECT [id],[handle],[namespace],[key],[value],[type],[description],[owner_resource],[is_from_template],[is_allow_multiple],[brand],[market]
        FROM [staging].[metafields]
) AS source ([id],[handle],[namespace],[key],[value],[type],[description],[owner_resource],[is_from_template],[is_allow_multiple],[brand],[market])
    ON HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CONCAT(destination.[id], destination.[handle], destination.[key], destination.[brand], destination.[market])) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CONCAT(source.[id], source.[handle], source.[key], source.[brand], source.[market]))
WHEN MATCHED AND destination.[value]!=source.[value]
    THEN UPDATE SET destination.[value]=source.[value]
                    ,destination.[modifiedDate]=GETDATE()
                    ,destination.[modifiedBy]=CURRENT_USER
    
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT ([id]
                ,[handle]
                ,[namespace]
                ,[key]
                ,[value]
                ,[type]
                ,[description]
                ,[owner_resource]
                ,[is_from_template]
                ,[is_allow_multiple]
                ,[brand]
                ,[market]
                ,[createdDate]
                ,[createdBy]
                ,[modifiedDate]
                ,[modifiedBy])
    VALUES      ([id]
                ,[handle]
                ,[namespace]
                ,[key]
                ,[value]
                ,[type]
                ,[description]
                ,[owner_resource]
                ,[is_from_template]
                ,[is_allow_multiple]
                ,[brand]
                ,[market]
                ,GETDATE()
                ,CURRENT_USER
                ,GETDATE()
                ,CURRENT_USER);
```

Answer (score 0):

the [id] was from different type one was bigint and the other varchar.